Python BeautifulSoup doesn't get full webpage html
I only get partial HTML response, this is my code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
 
url = requests.get("https://www.flashscore.co/tenis/rankings/atp/")
soup = bs(url, 'html.parser')
print(soup)

The script don`t get the data table
enter image description here
I Expect:
enter image description here

Have you looked at the page you get back from requests.get?  Remember that requests fetches the text of the page itself, and the text of the page does not include any of those statistics.  That's all generated on the fly by Javascript.  You would need Selenium.

Thanks, I think that, the data is being generated by javascript. What could I do?

Like @TimRoberts mentioned, you could use Selenium to go to the page and generate the JavaScript, and then try and scrape the generated data. You would need to find it on the page (I'd use chrome devtools for this) and go from there.

You need a package that runs a real browser to interpret the Javascript.  That means Selenium or requests-html.
